# How to generate Access token dynamically and use in POST Webhook call from Salesforce?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, webhooks

This is my Webhook trigger which was working before but now it needs Authorization to be added.

```
trigger OTWebhookTrigger on Contact (after update) {    
for(Integer i=0; i<trigger.new.size(); i++)
{
    if(trigger.new[i].Preferred_Language_Name__c != trigger.old[i].Preferred_Language_Name__c)
    {     
        if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
        {
            system.debug('Executed');
            String url = 'https://app.xxx.com/integrationmanager/api/v1/webhook/xxxxxxx';                                
            String content = Webhook.jsonContent(trigger.new[i].email, trigger.new[i].Preferred_Language_Name__c);               
            Webhook.callout(url, content);  
        }
    } 
}
```

}

I have got Client Id and Secret from third party application and I need to send Contact updates on a Webhook call. How do we dynamically generate Access token which refreshes automatically when it expires?

Comment: You'll use a Named Credentials to generate the OAuth session, then use that in your webhook callout code by replacing the current URL `https://app.onetrust.com/` with the Named Credential name `callout:oneTrustNC`.

Comment: And we need to define Client ID & Secret in Auth Provider right? I am receiving 'No Protocol' error!

Comment: @sfdcfox - Please add it as an Answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use a [Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) to generate the OAuth session, then use that in your webhook callout code by replacing the current URL `https://app.onetrust.com/` with the Named Credential name `callout:oneTrustNC`.